# Add space after colon zencoding-vim for .scss files

Tags: vim, sass, emmet

I am using the ZenCoding plugin for vim and I want it to expand CSS abbreviations by adding a space after every colon, which is not the current default behaviour for SCSS files.

I checked both Emmet's and zenconding-vim's documentation and I couldn't apply Emmet's custom property:

```
css.valueSeparator: ": "
```

to Vim. Which I tried by adding inside my `.vimrc` file.

```
let g:user_zen_settings = {
\  'css' : {
\    'valueSeparator' : ': '
\  }
\}
```

I am not sure whether I am missing something in ZenCoding's documentation or I am trying something that can't be done in ZenCoding.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer among zencoding-vim's issues:

https://github.com/mattn/zencoding-vim/issues/94

You must add this to to your `.vimrc` file:

```
let g:user_zen_settings = {
\  'scss' : {
\    'filters' : 'fc',
\  }
\}
```

**Important!** Don't miss the leading backslashes. They are required.